# Trying to find a specific object in Parse using just it's username JAVA

Tags: java, parsing

Using the code below I have created some users on a parse server.

```
ParseObject Score = new ParseObject("Score");
Score.put("username","Neil");
Score.put("score",8888);
Score.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {

      System.out.println("Succes");

    } else {

      System.out.println("Failure");

    }

  }
});
```

And

```
    ParseObject Score = new ParseObject("Score");
Score.put("username","Archie");
Score.put("score",9000);
Score.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {

      System.out.println("Succes");

    } else {

      System.out.println("Failure");

    }

  }
});
```

I am now trying to search for those users with by just their usernames.  So I want to search for the object with username "Neil" and return his score.  Could you please help me to do that?

I have made a few attempts but my understanding is too poor to say I've made progress that is worth posting.  Hopefully you will be able to show me the full code required to find the object that has the matching username and display it's score in the logs.

Thank you,

A

Comment: Why don't you fetch it from wherever you're saving it in?

Comment: Please show the code for the ParseObject class if you wrote it, or show which library it comes from if you didn't write it.  Of particular interest would be the code from the "save in background" method.  30k elevation answer: Your "Parse Server" needs to supply the search functionality and then you would access that functionality with something like a static method call `ParseObject archie = ParseServer.findByUsername("Archie")`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, convention is to start the names of objects with a lowercase letter, `Score` should be `score`, otherwise it looks to a human like a class's static method.

If you're using [this](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html) library, or one similar to it, then I'd recommend running through the array of `Score` objects you're saving and calling `score.get("username")` Something like

```
for (Score score : scores){
    score.fetch()
    if (score.get("username").equals("Neil")){
        System.out.println(score.get("score"));
    }
}
```

where `scores` is a collection of Score objects that you fetched.

If this isn't helpful, please add code for your Score class and let us know what library you're using.